# Ajax call on activeadmin filters

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activeadmin

I have a active admin filter "Tags" that contain all tags of users. Tags are loading in a collection.

The problem is what if we have thousands of tags? The page will take a lot of time to load all of them and them filter through them.

I wanted to make it dynamic through an AJAX call but I cannot find any resource related to this.

This is active admin filter

```
"filter :tags , label: 'Tags' , as: :select, collection: proc{ ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.order(id: :asc).uniq.pluck(:name, :id)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a popular problem. Therefore, there is a popular solution.

gem [activeadmin_addons](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons#search-select-filter) (search-select-filter)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score -1):

The question is a bit unclear, but from what I understood you want help on deciding whether you should load something dynamically or not.

I personally think that loading it through Ajax would be a good idea as this will save loading time. To do this you can just use jQuery Ajax as per below.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: { data:{/* data */} }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Source: [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

I hope this helps!